# How do I create an Area object using a PathIterator?

Tags: java, bufferedimage, shapes, area

I am clearly missing an important concept here. I have written code using mouse events to draw a boundary (a polygon) on an existing BufferedImage. Here is the relevant section:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
{
    super.paintComponent(g);  //Paint parent's background

    //G3 displays the BufferedImage "Drawing" with each paint
    Graphics2D G3 = (Graphics2D)g;
    G3.drawImage(this.Drawing, 0, 0, null);
    G3.dispose();
} 

public void updateDrawing()
{               
    int x0, y0, x1, y1; // Vertex coordinates
    Line2D.Float seg;
    // grafix is painting the mouse drawing to the BufferedImage "Drawing"     
    if(this.pts.size() > 0)
    {                   
        for(int ip = 0; ip < pts.size(); ip++)
        {
            x0 = (int)this.pts.get(ip).x;
            y0 = (int)this.pts.get(ip).y;
            this.grafix.drawRect(x0 - this.sqw/2, y0 - this.sqh/2, + this.sqw, this.sqh);
            if (ip > 0)
            {
                x1 = (int)this.pts.get(ip-1).x;
                y1 = (int)this.pts.get(ip-1).y; 
                this.grafix.drawLine(x1, y1, x0, y0);
                seg = new Line2D.Float(x1, y1, x0, y0);
                this.segments.add(seg);
            }
        }
    }
    repaint();
}
```

The next two routines are called by the mouse events: Left click gets the next point and right click closes the region.

```
public void getNextPoint(Point2D p)
{
    this.isDrawing = true;
    Point2D.Float next = new Point2D.Float();
    next.x = (float) p.getX();
    next.y = (float) p.getY();
    this.pts.add(next);
    updateDrawing();
}

public void closeBoundary()
{
    //Connects the last point to the first point to close the loop
    Point2D.Float next = new Point2D.Float(this.pts.get(0).x, this.pts.get(0).y);
    this.pts.add(next);
    this.isDrawing = false;
    updateDrawing();
}
```

It all works fine and I can save the image with my drawing on it:
[image with drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6AAf.png)
The list of vertices (pts) and the line segments (segments) are all that describe the region/shape/polygon.
I wish to extract from the original image only that region enclosed within the boundary. That is, I plan to create a new BufferedImage by moving through all of the pixels, testing to see if they fall within the figure and keep them if they do.
So I want to create an AREA from the points and segments I've collected in drawing the shape. Everything says: create an AREA variable and "getPathIterator". But on what shape? My AREA variable will be empty. How does the path iterator access the points in my list?

I've been all over the literature and this website as well.
I'm missing something.

Comment: Store all your points while painting, then create a [`Polygon`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html) from the points. If needed, create an `Area` from that (`new Area(polygon)`). But you can also create a `PathIterator` directly from the `Polygon`. It's hard to tell exactly why you want that though... Maybe some pseudo-code on what you try to do would help.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you haraldK for your suggestion. Before I saw your post, I came to a similar  conclusion:
Using the Arraylist of vertices from the paint operation, I populated a "Path2D.Float" object called "contour" by looping through the points list  that was created during the "painting" operation. Using this "contour" object, I instantiated an Area called "interferogram". Just to check my work, I created another PathIterator, "PI", from the Area and decomposed the Area, "interferogram" into "segments" sending the results to the console. I show the code below:

```
private void mnuitmKeepInsideActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                                 
{                                                     
    // Keeps the inner area of interest
    // Vertices is the "pts" list from Class MouseDrawing (mask)
    // It is already a closed path
    ArrayList<Point2D.Float> vertices = 
            new ArrayList<>(this.mask.getVertices()); 
    this.contour = new Path2D.Float(Path2D.WIND_NON_ZERO);

    // Read the vertices into the Path2D variable "contour"
    this.contour.moveTo((float)vertices.get(0).getX(), 
        (float)vertices.get(0).getY()); //Starting location

    for(int ivertex = 1; ivertex < vertices.size(); ivertex++)
    {
        this.contour.lineTo((float)vertices.get(ivertex).getX(), 
            (float)vertices.get(ivertex).getY());                           
    }      
    this.interferogram = new Area(this.contour);        
    PathIterator PI = this.interferogram.getPathIterator(null);

    //Test print out the segment types and vertices for debug
    float[] p = new float[6];
    int icount = 0;
    while( !PI.isDone())
    {
        int type = PI.currentSegment(p);
        System.out.print(icount);
        System.out.print(" Type " + type);
        System.out.print(" X " + p[0]);
        System.out.println(" Y " + p[1]);
        icount++;
        PI.next();
    }

    BufferedImage masked = Mask(this.image_out, this.interferogram);
    // Write image to file for debug
    String dir;
    dir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    dir = dir + "\\00masked.png";
    writeImage(masked, dir, "PNG");

}
```

Next, I applied the mask to the image testing each pixel for inclusion in the area using the code below:

```
public BufferedImage Mask(BufferedImage BIM, Area area)
{
    /** Loop through the pixels in the image and test each one for inclusion
    *   within the area.
    *   Change the colors of those outside
    **/

    Point2D p = new Point2D.Double(0,0);
    // rgb should be white
    int rgb = (255 << 24);
    for (int row = 0; row < BIM.getWidth(); row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < BIM.getHeight(); col++)
        {
            p.setLocation(col, row);
            if(!area.contains(p))
            {
                BIM.setRGB(col, row, rgb);
            }
        }
    }
    return BIM;
}
public static BufferedImage deepCopy(BufferedImage B2M) 
{
    ColorModel cm = B2M.getColorModel();
    boolean isAlphaPremultiplied = cm.isAlphaPremultiplied();
    WritableRaster raster = B2M.copyData(B2M.getRaster()
            .createCompatibleWritableRaster());
    return new BufferedImage(cm, raster, isAlphaPremultiplied, null);
}
```

This worked beautifully (I was surprised!) except for one slight detail: the lines of the area appeared around the outside of the masked image. 
In order to remedy this, I copied the original (resized) image before the painting operation. Many thanks to user1050755 (Nov 2014) for the routine **deepCopy** that I found on this website. Applying my mask to the copied image resulted in the portion of the original image I wanted without the mask lines. The result is shown in the attached picture. I am stoked!
[masked image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzMc6.png)